# Measure Theory by Halmos, theorem B, page 22

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

[image: This] This is an excerpt from Halmos' "Measure Theory" at page 22 and 23. This proof seems wrong to me. I could not prove that the class of all finite union of elements of $E$ is a ring of sets. I can only prove that if the set $E$ itself is a ring of sets. Is this proof right? If not, there is an alternative to the theorem?

$E$ is a set and $R(E)$ is the smallest ring containing $E$, the intersection of all rings containing $E$.

Comment: Of course you can't prove that "the class of all finite union[s] of elements of $E$ is a ring of sets." Halmos doesn't say that the class of all finite unions of elements of $E$ is a ring. He says that the class of all sets **which may be covered by** a finite union of sets of $E$ is a ring.

Comment: Maybe the word "covered" is confusing you?  Here it means "subset".  In other words, a set $F$ is covered by a finite union of sets in $\mathbf{E}$ if and only if there exist sets $A_1, \dots, A_n \in \mathbf{E}$ such that $F \subseteq A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n$.